# WooCommerce sale flash badge not showing in products page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, badge

My problem is: Basically, I am trying to show a sale badge whenever a product is on sale. I just found the way to do it and it is working fine, but only in the single product page. In single product pages, on related products, it shows the badge in the discounted products.

But in all products archive pages, it does not show anything.
This is the code I got for the single product pages:

```
function sales_badge( $text, $post, $product ) {
        return $tagType = '<span class="onsale"><img style="max-width: 150px;" src="sale.jpg"></span>';
}
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'sales_badge', 99, 3 );
```

For the theme we are using: Astra and Elementor. I have tried everything possible and I tried to search over the web without finding anything related with it.

Note that I am not using any plugin for this and don't want to.

Comment: I just edited the question and added the code. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Just answered your question then…